# How to sum transaction amounts for different time intervals in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say I have table called Transactions and have 3 following columns:

```
Customerid
TranscationDate
TransactionAmount
```

So I need to sum transaction amounts for each customer in different date intervals. For example, transaction amount for last 10 days, transaction amount from last 10 days to last 30 days and etc..

this is what I have tried. It work, but running time is **ultimately** slow.

```
select customerid
,SUM ( case when transactiondate > @date1 and TOPUPDATE <@date0 then transactionamount else 0 end) AS Amount_last10
,SUM ( case when transactiondate > @date2 and TOPUPDATE <@date1 then transactionamount else 0 end) AS Amountlast10_to_last20


,SUM ( case when transactiondate > @date1 and TOPUPDATE <@date0 then transactionamount else 0 end) AS count_last10
,SUM ( case when transactiondate > @date2 and TOPUPDATE <@date1 then transactionamount else 0 end) AS count_last10_to_20

from TransactionData t
group by customerid
```

For better understanding I write down what I need

```
Customer_id  Amount_last10   Amountlast10_to_last20    count_last10    count_last10_to_20
11234        100             200                          3             1
```

Please consider that I have many many rows, so I need make my query running time as less as possible.

Comment: Have you considered using `SUM`? What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and sorry for not writing what I have tried, i update question pls look at again.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text, and you current query (even if it is not working, it is important to show your attempt).

Comment: Then show your query. If you're *actually* asking how to improve the speed of the query that is a **completely** different question. What are you *really* asking here?

Comment: Speedoptimization might heavily depend on your table, indexes and queries. some things might not profit by indexing (f.e. a string inside other string search) - a datetime between Y and Z might.. We would need far more detail that whats currently on the question to help here

Comment: please look at question again, I give more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want conditional aggregation:

```
select Customerid, sum(TransactionAmount) as amount_total,
       sum(case when datediff(day, TransactionDate, getdate()) between 0 and 9
                then TransactionAmount else 0
           end) as total_0_9,
       sum(case when datediff(day, TransactionDate, getdate()) between 10 and 19
                then TransactionAmount else 0
           end) as total_10_19,
       . . .
from Transactions t
group by Customerid;
```

For performance, you should add a `where` clause so you only aggregate the data you need.  For instance, for the above two columns:

```
where TransactionDate >= dateadd(day, -19, convert(date, getdate())
```